# <video> element displays only control bar

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have a H.264 video I want to show it on Chrome using HTML5 but using this video tag I only see a control bar.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="myvideo.264" type="video/264" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If someone has experience here, please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your file extension to 'mp4' and your type attribute to 'video/mp4'.

For extra credit, you may want to have a Flash fallback for Firefox, which does not play H.264/MP4 video (yet). You can use something like [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) or [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) to handle this for you.